# Modifiers causing internal compilation error

Tags: solidity, modifiers

My modifiers are throwing internal compilation errors: Internal compiler error: Identifier type not expected in expression context.

```
modifier critical {
    if (mutex) throw;
    mutex = true;
    _;
    mutex = false;
}

function createPlayer() {
    critical; 
    var player = players[msg.sender];
    if (player.ready) { throw; }
    player.ethaddress = msg.sender;
    player.creationdate = block.timestamp; 
    player.balance += msg.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createPlayer() critical {
// Not
function createPlayer() {
    critical;
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifiers are specified after the function, like:

```
function createPlayer() critical {
    ...
}
```